# Total of Selected Items in Gridview

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview, calculated-columns

I have a Gridview

[image]

I have Click Button and two labels. (Risk_label and MV_label)

Risk and MV column has price value.

My Checkbox column names are `NameCheckBoxField1` and `NameCheckBoxField2`

How can i calculate only "Which i selected in Gridview" Risk total and MV total in my labels?

Example;

```
Risk (Checked rows) --> 10, 20, 30 ---> Risk_label = 60
MV (Checked rows) --> 20, 30, 40 ---> MV_label = 90
```

**EDİT**: I try this code;

```
double sum = 0;
foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
{
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gvr.FindControl("NameCheckBoxField1");
    if (cb.Checked)
    {
        double amount = Convert.ToDouble(gvr.Cells[1].Text);
        sum += amount;
    }
}
Risk_label.Text = sum.ToString();
```

But i getting an error.

Comment: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." in this code line if (cb.Checked) ??

Comment: Did you check the column name ( NameCheckBoxField1 ) is correct? Looks like FindControl doesn't return the CheckBox

Comment: @Morten I defined like that <asp:templatefield headertext="">
            <itemtemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox DataField="NameCheckBoxField1" Checked="True" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
            </itemtemplate>
            </asp:templatefield>

Comment: Try giving your checkbox an Id and reference that from FindControl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void CalculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Int32 totalMVValue = 0, totalRiskValue = 0;

            // Iterate through the Products.Rows property
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                // Access the CheckBox
                CheckBox mvSelectorCheckBox = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("MVSelector");
                if (mvSelectorCheckBox != null && mvSelectorCheckBox.Checked)
                {
                    // First, get the primaryId for the selected row
                    int mvValue=
                        Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);
                    totalMVValue += mvValue;
                }

                CheckBox riskSelectorCheckBox = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("RiskSelector");
                if (riskSelectorCheckBox != null && riskSelectorCheckBox.Checked)
                {
                    // First, get the primaryId for the selected row
                    int riskValue =
                        Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);
                    totalRiskValue += riskValue;
                }
            }           
        }
```

Looking at your last comment:

```
 <asp:templatefield headertext=""> <itemtemplate> <asp:CheckBox DataField="NameCheckBoxField1" Checked="True" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox> </itemtemplate> </asp:templatefield>
```

Is DataField assigned NameCheckBoxField1? Or is it a typo?
It should be `ID="NameCheckBoxField1"`

Comment: What is MVSelector and RiskSelector? This code workd but both value getting "0". MVSelector is mine NameCheckBoxField1 RİGHT??  <asp:templatefield headertext="">
            <itemtemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox DataField="NameCheckBoxField1" ID="NameCheckBoxField1" Checked="True" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
            </itemtemplate>
            </asp:templatefield> RIGHT??

Comment: Yes right. You could replace them with whatever id is given to the checkboxes in the markup.

Answer (score 1):

I think jQuery would be the best option for you.
1. Add classes for Risk_Label and MV_Label 
2. On checkbox click get the value of Risk_Label and MV_Label of the same row using the classes.
3. If it is checked then add value other wise subtract values.

```
    $('.mygrid :checkbox').click(function () {

                            var amt = parseFloat($(this).parents('tr').find('.ClassRisk_label').text());
                            //One Fee Case
                            if (!isNaN(amt)) {
                                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                                    totalAmt = totalAmt + amt;
                                }
                                else {
                                    totalAmt = totalAmt - amt;
                                }
                            }
//Show the value...
});
```